# Where would my emails go if I set an alias?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I have a microsoft account that I have some files on. Now I want to add my other microsoft account that I have some files on that too as an alias to the first account. What will happen to my files? And where would my emails go? Imagine I have OneNote notes on both of the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alias to the MS Account has no impact on the Account itself. Just a different email address used to log into the account.

The files that belonged to two different accounts will remain unchanged.

Comment: Imagine I have created an MS account using gmail address. Now I want to send an email to that account. But I have a gmail account associated with that address. So if I send an email to that address, where would it go? And if I want to send an email to MS account what should I do?